# Variable-Length Lookbehind not work in perl file, but work in one-liner

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

If I put `s/(?<!(?:href|src)=.{0,40})jpg//g` in a perl file, and try to run it, it will give the warning: `Variable length lookbehind is experimental in regex; marked by` and fail.

But if put in a perl one-liner, it will run successfully, although still be warned of `Variable length lookbehind is experimental in regex; marked by`.

Is it by current design or maybe I'm using it wrong?

Update: I'm using perl 5.31.3

Comment: That message is a warning, it shouldn't actually cause anything to fail. Either you enabled fatal warnings in your script, or the problem actually lies elsewhere.

Comment: I indeed enabled fatal warning. After I changed it to `use warnings;` or as Wiktor Stribiżew pointed out, add a `no warnings qw(experimental::vlb);`,  it can run successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before v5.30, a positive lookbehind with indeterminate, "variable width" pattern fails to compile with the *`Variable length lookbehind not implemented`* error.

**In v5.30, you [are allowed](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Limited-variable-length-lookbehind-in-regular-expression-pattern-matching-is-now-experimentally-supported) to use a lookbehind pattern that can match up to 255 chars.**

> Using a lookbehind assertion (like `(?<=foo?)` or `(?<!ba{1,9}r)`
> previously would generate an error and refuse to compile. Now it
> compiles (if the maximum lookbehind is at most 255 characters), but
> raises a warning in the new `experimental::vlb` warnings category. This
> is to caution you that the precise behavior is subject to change based
> on feedback from use in the field.

If you use `(?<=WORD\s+)`, you will get a *`Lookbehind longer than 255 not implemented`* error since the regex engine needs to know in advance that the length of the subpattern won't be longer than 255 and the `+` quantifier has an indeterminate length. So, `(?<=WORD\s{0,255})` would work.

In your case, you know your lookbehind pattern will never match more than 255 chars, so just turn that experimental warning like any other experimental warnings:

```perl
no warnings qw(experimental::vlb);
```

Note: Make sure that the above line is placed *after* the `use warnings;` line, if present, or it will have no lasting effect, being overridden by `use warnings;`.

Comment: The caveat is that, as an experimental features, it may have bugs, it may change without notice, and it may be removed without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Perl doesn't care if the code is provided via `-e` or via a file. The code behaves identically in both situations. The reason it fails is not because you used the code you posted in a file instead of on the command line. There is another difference you haven't identified causing the difference in behaviour.

---

That said you shouldn't use the cost you posted. As the warning loudly announces, this is an *experimental feature*. It is unproven, and thus potentially problematic. Also, it is subject to change and removal without further notice.

You can eliminate the use of the experimental variable-length lookbehind by using the following instead:

```perl
s/(?:href|src).{0,40}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|jpg//g
```

`(*FAIL)` causes the pattern not to match, and thus trigger backtracking. But `(*SKIP)` made it so that it will start matching at the position after the string matched by `(?:href|src).{0,40}` in future attempts.