# sed and Perl regexp replaces once, with multiple replacements flag

Tags: regex, perl, sed, regex-greedy, regexp-replace

I have the string:

```sh
lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym"
```

I want the line to be:

```sh
lopy,lopy1,sym,lady,lady1,sym
```

Which means that all "lad" after the string sym should be replaced. So I ran:

```sh
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" | sed -r 's/(.*sym.*?)lopy/\1lad/g'
```

I get:

```sh
lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lad1,sym
```

Using Perl is not really better:

```sh
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" | perl -pe 's/(.*sym.+?)lopy/${1}lad/g'
```

yields

```
lopy,lopy1,sym,lad,lopy1,sym
```

Not all "lopy" are replaced. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `(.*sym.*?)lopy` / `(.*sym.+?)lopy` patterns are almost the same, `.+?` matches one or more chars other than line break chars, but as few as possible, and `.*?` matches zero or more such chars. Mind that `sed` does not support lazy quantifiers, `*?` is the same as `*` in `sed`. However, the main problem with the regexps you used is that they match `sym`, then any text after it and then `lopy`, so when you added `g`, it just means you want to find more cases of `lopy` after `sym....lopy`. And there  is only one such occurrence in your string.

You want to replace all `lopy` after `sym`, so you can use

```sh
perl -pe 's/(?:\G(?!^)|sym).*?\Klopy/lad/g'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDOZaa/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|sym)` - `sym` or end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`)
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `lopy` - a `lopy` string.

See the online demo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" | perl -pe 's/(?:\G(?!^)|sym).*?\Klopy/lad/g'
# => lopy,lopy1,sym,lad,lad1,sym
```

If the values are always comma separated, you may replace `.*?` with `,`: `(?:\G(?!^)|sym),\Klopy` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDOZaa/2)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `lopy`(s) to replace are after `sym`, with a pattern like `sym.*?lopy`, so a global replacement looks for yet more of the whole `sym`+`lopy`-after-`sym` (not just for all `lopy`s after that one `sym`).<sup>†</sup>

To replace all `lopy`s (after the first `sym`, followed by another `sym`) we can capture the substring between `sym`s and in the replacement side run code, in which a regex replaces all `lopy`s

```
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" | 
    perl -pe's{ sym,\K (.+?) (?=sym) }{ $1 =~ s/lop/lad/gr }ex'
```

To isolate the substring between `sym`s I use `\K` after the first `sym`, which drops matches prior to it, and a positive lookahead for the `sym` after the substring, which doesn't consume anything.  The `/e` modifier makes the replacement side be evaluated as code.  In the replacement side's regex we need `/r` since `$1` can't change, and we want the regex to return anyway. See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut).

---

<sup>†</sup>  To match all of `abbbb` we can't say `/ab/g`, nor `/(a)b/g` nor `/a(b)/g`, because that would look for all repetitions of the whole `ab` in the string (and find only `ab` in the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

Since OP has mentioned `sed` so I am adding `awk` program here. Which could be better choice in comparison to `sed`. With shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" | 
awk -F',sym,' '
{
  first=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
  gsub(/lop/,"lad")
  $0=first FS $0
}
1
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" |  ##Printing values and sending as standard output to awk program as an input.
awk -F',sym,' '                         ##Making ,sym, as a field separator here.
{
  first=$1                              ##Creating first which has $1 of current line in it.
  $1=""                                 ##Nullifying $1 here.
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")               ##Substituting initial space in current line here.
  gsub(/lop/,"lad")                     ##Globally substituting lop with lad in rest of line.
  $0=first FS $0                        ##Adding first FS to rest of edited line here.
}
1                                       ##Printing edited/non-edited line value here.
'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not support non-greedy wildcards at all. But your Perl script also fails for other reasons; you are saying "match all occurrences of this" but then you specify a regex which can only match once.

A common simple solution is to split the string, and then replace only after the match:

```sh
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" |
perl -pe 'if (@x = /^(.*?sym,)(.*)/) { $x[1] =~ s/lop/lad/g; s/.*/$x[0]$x[1]/ }'
```

If you want to be fancy, you can use a lookbehind to only replace the `lop` occurrences after the first `sym`.

```
echo "lopy,lopy1,sym,lopy,lopy1,sym" |
perl -pe 's/(?<=sym.{0,200})lop/lad/'
```

The variable-length lookbehind generates a warning and is only supported in Perl 5.30+ ([you can turn it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619186/variable-length-lookbehind-not-work-in-perl-file-but-work-in-one-liner) with `no warnings qw(experimental::vlb));`.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have shown an attempted `sed` command and used `sed` tag, here is a `sed` loop based solution:

```sh
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's~(sym,.*)lopy~\1lady~g; ta' file

lopy,lopy1,sym,lady,lady1,sym"
```

**Explanation:**

- `:a` sets a label `a` before matching `sym,.*` pattern
- `ta` jumps pattern matching back to label `a` after making a substitution

This looping stop when `s` command has nothing to match i.e. no `lopy` substring after `sym,`